# Javascript/jQuery - waiting until function complete before running the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a button which when it gets clicked triggers a function. The function does some stuff (reverse geocodes a latitude/longitude) and then fills a hidden form input with a value.

I need the input to have the correct value before the rest of the code I need gets executed, is there a way to do this? At the moment I have

```
$('.addButton').click(function() { 
    //first run the reverse geocode to update the hidden location input with the readable address
    reversegeocode();
    var location = $("#location").val();//the value I need
    $.post("<?php echo $this->webroot;?>locations/add", {location:location})
        .done(function (data) {
            $("#locationsHolder").html(data);
        });
});
```

So basically I don't want to get the value from the input and post it via AJAX until I know that the `reversegeocode()` function has finished

Can anyone please explain how I can go about this. I've read some stuff about deferment but I'm absolutely useless at figuring out Javascript and I'm really struggling.

Thanks

EDIT:

Here's my reversegeocode funciton

```
function reversegeocode(){
    var lat = $('#lattitude').val();
    var lng = $('#longitude').val();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (results[0]) {//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082405/parsing-address-components-in-google-maps-upon-autocomplete-select
              var address_components = results[0].address_components;
              var components={}; 
                jQuery.each(address_components, function(k,v1) {jQuery.each(v1.types, function(k2, v2){components[v2]=v1.long_name});})
            var output = '';
            var needAcomma = false;
            if(components.route != undefined) {
                output += components.route;
                needAcomma = true;
            }
            if(components.locality != undefined) {
                if(needAcomma) {
                    output += ', ';
                }
                output += components.locality;
                needAcomma = true;
            }
            if(components.administrative_area_level_1 != undefined) {
                if(needAcomma) {
                    output += ', ';
                }
                output += components.administrative_area_level_1;
                needAcomma = true;
            }else if(components.administrative_area_level_2 != undefined) {
                if(needAcomma) {
                    output += ', ';
                }
                output += components.administrative_area_level_2;
                needAcomma = true;
            }else if(components.administrative_area_level_3 != undefined) {
                if(needAcomma) {
                    output += ', ';
                }
                output += components.administrative_area_level_3;
                needAcomma = true;
            }
            $("#location").val(output);
          } else {
            alert('No results found');
          }
        } else {
          alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: looks like `reversegeocode` is an asynchronous method, you need to share that method for us to see what can be done. Any way the `reversegeocode` method need to provide some kind of callback facility to let us know when it is completed

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've stuck my function in my question. it just gets the address from google and sticks the result in an input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `reversegeocode` is a asynchronous method, you need to use a callback based solution. `reversegeocode` should receive a callback method as a argument and then invoke the callback once the geocoding is completed.

```
$('.addButton').click(function () {
    //pass a callback to reversegeocode which will get called once the geocoding is completed
    reversegeocode(function (location) {
        //the callback receives the location as a parameter
        $.post("<?php echo $this->webroot;?>locations/add", {
            location: location
        })
            .done(function (data) {
            $("#locationsHolder").html(data);
        });
    });
});

function reversegeocode(callback) {
    var lat = $('#lattitude').val();
    var lng = $('#longitude').val();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': latlng
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) { //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082405/parsing-address-components-in-google-maps-upon-autocomplete-select
                var address_components = results[0].address_components;
                var components = {};
                jQuery.each(address_components, function (k, v1) {
                    jQuery.each(v1.types, function (k2, v2) {
                        components[v2] = v1.long_name
                    });
                })
                var output = '';
                var needAcomma = false;
                if (components.route != undefined) {
                    output += components.route;
                    needAcomma = true;
                }
                if (components.locality != undefined) {
                    if (needAcomma) {
                        output += ', ';
                    }
                    output += components.locality;
                    needAcomma = true;
                }
                if (components.administrative_area_level_1 != undefined) {
                    if (needAcomma) {
                        output += ', ';
                    }
                    output += components.administrative_area_level_1;
                    needAcomma = true;
                } else if (components.administrative_area_level_2 != undefined) {
                    if (needAcomma) {
                        output += ', ';
                    }
                    output += components.administrative_area_level_2;
                    needAcomma = true;
                } else if (components.administrative_area_level_3 != undefined) {
                    if (needAcomma) {
                        output += ', ';
                    }
                    output += components.administrative_area_level_3;
                    needAcomma = true;
                }
                $("#location").val(output);
                //call the callback
                callback(output);
            } else {
                alert('No results found');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `reversegeocode` to take a `callback` parameter (also known as a `continuation`).

Encapsulate all the stuff that needs to wait for `reversegeocode` to finish, putting it into an in-place, nameless function.

(Note the similarity to what you're already doing for the `click` handler.)

With this approach you are also free to add parameters to the callback, which you can use to pass data directly through.

```
$('.addButton').click(function() { 
    reversegeocode(function(some_data) {
        var location = $("#location").val();//the value I need
        //...stuff...
    });
});

function reversegeocode(callback){
    //...stuff...
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          //...stuff...
        } else {
          alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
        callback(some_data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a callback function in the `reversegeocode` function.

Answer (score 0):

The same exact way as you do ajax :)

```
$('.addButton').click(function() { 
    reversegeocode().done(function(location) {
        $.post("<?php echo $this->webroot;?>locations/add", {location:location})
            .done(function (data) {
                $("#locationsHolder").html(data);
            });
    });
})
```

To do this you will have reversegeocode return a [jquery deferred promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

```
function reversegeocode() {
  return $.Deferred(function(d) {
    //do stuff and when it succeeds
    d.resolve(location);
    //or if it fails
    d.reject("something went wrong");
  }).promise();
}
```

Comment: Hi George - cool mustache by the way - I'm not sure I understand the return bit of this. I don't actually need it to return anything, is it not possible to do this without having to return anything?

Comment: @crazysarah You could, you certainly don't have to return anything (and then you wouldn't get a (location) parameter. However I recommend  separating the component that does the reverse geocoding and the process of actually setting it in the UI. Return the location, and in one `done` handler set the `#locationsHolder` html and in another `done` handler do what I did above (read the deferred documentation if this is confusing to you). You shouldn't use html in the UI to communicate between functions - there's already a mechanism for that: parameters and return values.